# how may I do instrumental variable logistic regression?

Tags: r, binary-data, logistic

```
set.seed(123)
n <-1000
stage <- rbinom(n,1,0.5)
age <- rnorm(n,68,20)
sofa <- round(rnorm(n,10,3))#0-24, an unobserved variable
percent <- 0.5*stage+
 rnorm(n,0.7,0.01)-
0.001*age-0.03*sofa
linpred <-0.1*sofa-
 percent+
0.01*age-1.1
prob <- exp(linpred)/(1+exp(linpred))
mort<-ifelse(runif(n,0,1)<prob,1,0)
dt<-data.frame(stage=stage,
percent=percent,
age=age,
mort=mort,
cost=cost)
mod.mort<-glm(mort~percent+age,
family = "binomial",dt)##sofa is unobserved in reality
summary(mod.mort)
```

because the variable percent is endogeneous, I cannot perform logistic regression to estimate the effect of percent on mort. We need to use instrumental variable (stage) to instrument the estimation. I know `ivreg()` function can perform IV analysis, but it is only for continuous outcome. How can I perform binary outcome as in the artificial example? Can anybody provide detailed R code for the analysis?